# how to build dash components from React components library?

Tags: python, reactjs, plotly-dash

The Front End team at my company has built several React components. Those components are made available to other Front End devs as a library which can be installed with npm.

I'd like to convert these components into Dash components to make them easy to use for Python devs in Dash and replicate (as close as possible) the same look & feel as React apps. What would be the best approach to create Dash components from a React library?

I've gone through the documentation :

- [React for Python Developers](https://dash.plotly.com/react-for-python-developers)
- [Build your Own Components](https://dash.plotly.com/plugins)

The approach proposed in the documentation is to write the React components and transform the components into Dash.

I tried the following steps:

- clone the React repo
- clone the Dash component template
- use cookiecutter to generate the boilerplate code
- copy the React code from React repo into the generated folder
- run `npm build`

This did not work so far, I assume because of dependencies and node version.

Is there an easier way? i.e. Is it possible to use the library directly to build the dash components?

Comment: You can try out the following package to use the react components directly in your Dash apps: https://github.com/TomaszRewak/dash-local-react-components